# Why does go require you to add & before a variable name?

Tags: go

Here is a snippet that I am looking at:

```
var t txn
t.c = c
err := c.read(&t.req)
```

Why do you have to write &t and not just t.req?

Comment: This isn't a Go question specifically.  When you use the & operator in front of a variable, it returns the address of the variable.  For example,

int i = 3;
int *i_ptr = &i;

The read function takes a pointer to the request, so using & gives you the pointer you need.

Comment: @DigitalGhost: Yes, I'd say it is specifically a Go question. It could also be a C or C++ question because they happen to share that particular feature, but plenty of languages don't.

Comment: @DigitalGhost if it needs a pointer, you just said it returns the address?

Comment: If you don't understand what this does, checkout http://tour.golang.org/#26 and run the example. Remove the `&` and run again, inspecting the output. Print out `q` instead of `p`. Go lets you pass by value which automatically makes a copy of something, versus pass by reference which is what you see as standard in scripting languages. Use of `&` produces behaviour like what one sees in scripting languages.

Answer (score 6):

You don't always have to use the ampersand. In your example it depends on the signature of c.read, which asks for a pointer (`*` before the type, such as `*MyStruct`). `&` returns the address of a value, giving you a pointer to it, so `&t.req` satisfies read's signature.

For further reading, see the [FAQ on pointers](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Pointers) and the spec on [Address operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators).